# Highlight if duplicate in cell range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I need a solution to highlight all identical cells in cell range C2:I7 with color background 'green'.

I tried using the `=countif` and `=countifs(C2:I7;C2)>1` and a lot of similar adjustments to this. I can only get it to highlight all but 1 or more of the identical cells.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSfBYKUzCWPCroBKVKACJCrocmPsvjgLcjgF7FDzFTepFcG1YdJx85e39rUaCBSUCqlaHzXPOpUNkPO/pubhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lock the range C2:I7

```
=countifs($C$2:$I$7;C2)>1
```

Conditional formatting assumes relative addressing. So if you look at the letter D at the end of the second row (I3) for example, the effect of your original formula is

```
=countifs(I3:O8;I3)>1
```

and there are no additional D's within that range.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Tom! I tried different locks but not the most logical one! :)

Comment: You're welcome - took me a while to understand that when I first messed about with CF.